# Выборка уникальных значений столбца из отсортированной таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY, после сортировки которой мы получаем следующий её вид:
[image: ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY]

Теперь же, необходимо из полученных данных выбрать только колонку PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID, которая, сохранив порядок сортировки, предоставит значения, которые будут уникальными.

Comment: группируйте и сортируйте например по `min(excel_order)` раз вам уникальные нужны, думаю первый раз когда значение было встречено в самый раз будет

Comment: А что вам мешает вместо вместо 'select * ' написать select distinct PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID в вашем запросе?

Comment: Вот это: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: @Mike не понял...:)

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, это то, что нужно! Добавьте ваш вариант как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
  from table
 where ...
 group by PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
 order by min(excel_order)
```